# String Connection excel .xls .xlsx C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, xls

Eu tenho uma string de conexão com o excel, mas é somente a .xlsx e está dando esse erro

> ServerVersion = 'connExcel.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'

eu preciso de uma conexão com as duas ao mesmo tempo, pois posso ter os 2 tipos de arquivo na hora de ler.

```
string strExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                "Data Source = " + txtArquivo.Text + ";" + "Extend Properties=Excel 12.0 xml; HDR = YES";
```

Answer (score 2):

Quando tenho dúvidas sobre uma Connection String, eu consulto o site http://www.connectionstrings.com/ .

Na seção Excel em http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/, tem vários tipos de conexão.

Creio que o tipo que pode atender você para xls e xlsx é a Standard ODBC http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007-odbc/standard/

```
Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};
DBQ=C:\MyExcel.xlsx;
```

Comment: Essa string que estou usando é da connectionstring.com, estou confuso por não estar funcionando comigo. Verei essa Standar e postarei a experiência.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tentei com a string Standard ODBC, sem sucesso... 
Segue abaixo o código...

```
    //Conexão com o Excel 
    OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection("@PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0 xml;Data source=" + txtArquivo + ";" + 
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; HDR=YES");


    try
    {

        //Comando oledb excel
        OleDbCommand commExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        commExcel.Connection = connExcel;

        string alertaPasta = "Selecione uma pasta";
        string titulo = "Alerta";

        //Se o txtArquivo for Nulo ou o espaço estiver em branco {exiba alerta}
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtArquivo.Text))
        {
            DialogResult resultadoAlerta = MessageBox.Show(alertaPasta, titulo);
            return;
        }

        //se o estado da conexão não estiver aberto, abra.
        if (connExcel.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            connExcel.Open();

        //Leitura das Sheets

        DataTable dtExcel;
        dtExcel = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string sheetName = dtExcel.Rows[0]["TABLE NAME"].ToString();

        commExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        connExcel.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Então, eu descobri que passando a string só da pasta, ele não conecta, preciso passar a string do arquivo .xls/xlsx.